# How to handle deleted local storage in React?

Tags: reactjs, session, redux, local-storage

My React app saves a session token in local storage. Several components rely on this token and so if one were to delete local storage (say using the chrome developer tools), then try use one of these components, the component will not work appropriately.

For example, in creating a blog post this code is called:

```
function getToken() {
  return localStorage.getItem(token)
}
```

which will not be able to produce the token and the blog post will not get sent out.

When I try deleting local storage on well known websites and then proceed to route to a different page, local storage is restored when I check it using the developer tools.

Does anybody have experience with handling local storage and handling the case where local storage is deleted.

Some possible solutions that I could think of are:

- Check if local storage exists when a component is rendered and try re-fetch the token if it does not, then re-set the local storage. (This might suck to do in each component).
- Save the token in the Redux store, if local storage is deleted then get token from the store. *But* what if I delete local storage and then do a hard refresh of the page. Then the store will be cleared and the token will not be in either the store or local storage. When I try do this in well known websites it handles if just fine.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify why you are attempting to directly get `token` from [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) rather than using the `localStorage.getItem('token')`? You aren't setting `token` on `localStorage` like `localStorage.token = 'someTokenValue'` right? You are using `localStorage.setItem('token', 'someTokenValue')` right because that would be how the API specifies to set values. Can you also clarify what you mean by `localStorage` being deleted? `Window.localStorage` is never really deleted.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know of this and will implement it and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I should actually clarify, technically you can directly get and set values on the `localStorage`, it's just not recommended. At a very basic level, you can use a simple `if` statement to check if `token` exists on `localStorage` and re-fetch accordingly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Testing_whether_your_storage_has_been_populated

Comment: Thank you, I always prefer to do things the better way so I will adopt your suggestion. I was indeed using an if statement to check the local storage and setting it directly but your method is cleaner.